# Имея доступ к root в docker, могу ли я получить доступ к настоящей машине?

Tags: c++, linux, python-3.x, docker, alpine-linux

Я могу запускать любой код на С++, python3, java8 в докере и имею доступ в интернет(за NAT). Время работы докер-контейнера около 20 секунд после он автоматически выключается и переходит в изначальное состояние. Можно ли как либо получить доступ к основной машине. На docker Alpine-linux

И еще какие данные мне добавить к вопросу?

Comment: Да, если ты найдёшь незакрытую уязвимость и успеешь ей воспользоваться.

Comment: http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=50765 ну собственно.